# Form loads, but fails to submit, django-ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

I am having trouble getting my form to submit. The problem seems to be unique to loading the form into a particular page. The form functions perfectly if not loaded and accessed manually by typing the url. Also, the form accessed manually doesn't function if `method="POST"` is removed from the form designation.

excerpt from views.py to manage form

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectMyBookForm(request.POST, choices=choices)
        # do stuff
```

So my question is this:

Is the reason the form is not submitting properly in the loaded case because the "POST" request is not taking place at the correct url? How can I get the "POST" request to be recognized? Can I use Ajax (as in activate.js) to get around this condition in django?

I used the JQuery load() function to load a form on another page. The form renders correctly, but fails to submit when the button is pressed. I attempted to write a function in Javascript to help correct this issue. `#submitform` refers to the button that will submit the form `#bookselect` is the id of the form itself.

from activate.js

```
    $("#bookselect").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = getElementsByTagName('course_link');
        var pk = elem.attr('data');
        var cond = $("li.tab.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: selectConditionURL(pk, cond),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Quite a few issues. To start off, remove the click handler to start off. Also, you dont need the return false at the end, as you are doing a `preventDefault`. Next, you are not sending the POST data.

Comment: How can I remove the click handler? It should still only submit on clicking the submit button correct? I don't want the form to automatically submit.

Comment: Right. it triggers only on submit of the form. assuming that `bookselect` is the form id

Comment: karthikr, could you clarify about sending the POST data?

Comment: Is `$("#bookselect").submit` running? Does your server receives anything at all? Or nothing happens?